# Block phone functions while using HTML5 web application

Tags: android, ios, html, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I am currently working on a project developing a basic application. The customer require the application to block phone functions (calls, messages, etc.) while being used. They prefer a HTML5 implementation rather than IOS/Andriod.

Is it achievable to block phone functions with a ASP.NET HTML5 application?

Comment: Thankfully, iOS has no support for this (using any public APIs at least).

Comment: Not on Android either with just HTML5 web app. Remember that the website itself is in the browser sandbox. That sounds like a security violation and it helps to think in terms of bad actors when talking with clients and their goals.

Comment: Incomming calls can be blocked on iOS but not without a native app implementation.